# Unable insert data into Postgresql database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, postgresql-9.3, asp.net-core-1.0

I was unable to add user on PostgreSql database on Windows Server 2016.
This is my code to add a user:

```
user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = customer.LookupKey, Guid = customer.Guid };
var password = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 8).ToString();
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

This code works fine on my localhost, but when me publish to the Windows server 2016, it won't add the data.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 5 is running on the **full** .NET Framework - yet you also tag ASP.NET Core 1.0 - which are you using now?? The full .NET Framework with MVC 5, or ASP.NET Core 1.0 (presumably with ASP.NET Core MVC)

Comment: ASP.NET Core 1.0